# Why am I not motivated?

Tags: discipline

I feel like I want to write, but when I do it just gets boring.
I begin thinking, "Oh, I'm probably just gonna start a new draft. What even is the point."

I really do enjoy writing, I'm a person that keeps my feelings inside and when I like something or have an obsession the only person I talk to is the white paper.

But like I said earlier, basically when I start writing I get bored.

**Q** *Is there a cause I'm getting bored?*

Comment: How quickly do you get bored?

Comment: Usually after 10 minutes

Comment: Have you tried setting yourself goals to reach? Maybe word counts, or a whole day (in story time), just writing a single conversation could help if you have something to aim for.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Most importantly make sure you are writing something you really care about (as long as we're not talking about your day-to-day job here). No hobby is made better by forcing yourself to do only what you think others will appreciate rather than what you truly love to create.

As for getting bored in the creative process, and this is just a personal annecdote, but I find that I am unable to really focus on writing or programming when I have been habitually inundating myself with easy stimuli. Things like using my phone too often, playing video games or binging on Netflix, all draw power from my ability to sit down and really pour myself into my true hobby.

Either way, if you find yourself not performing how you would like to, then that just means it's time to change something. So experiment with variables in your days' activities and see what gets that productivity churning!

Comment: +1... I like this answer.  I can relate to you being a fellow programmer too who also enjoys writing.  I find myself falling victim to mobile games and binge watching on crunchyroll.  Partially also I am just too tired to do anything after I get home.  As you know programming can be fairly draining.  It's just too easy to plop down on the couch and zone out ><

Answer (score 3):

Like the user above has said it's crucial to keep experimenting with your craft. It's the only way we can keep being motivated. Sticking to a single method will eventually turn tiresome and boring in time. If you're clearly not interested in what you're doing it is a sign you need to change your method.

Now I do have to add something here. The most interesting idea is the one you're beginning to write. The most boring one is when you're stuck at page 80. And it's crucial to get till the boring stage if you need to get better. Every idea in your head is going to feel spectacular and it will always turn boring at one point when you put it in paper. Don't get the idea that a writer must absolutely love every minute of this process.

In short, my point is that you need to force yourself and get your ideas out. It's the only way to break free from this. If you still get bored you may want to think twice about your method. Not every story teller is a novelist.

Answer (score 1):

For me boredom is usually a sign that I'm lacking focus and the easiest way to force myself to focus is to have deadlines.

Deadlines can be external (I need to have a clean draft to the writing group by Sunday night at 10pm, the contest submission is next Tuesday, etc.) or internal (see the pomodoro technique), but just knowing I need to make progress is enough to get me moving forward.